increase google sheet sending quotas
We use Google tables, we made a script for notification by mail gmail, only quotas of 100 pieces per day is possible. What tariff do I need Google Workspace to increase quotas. Business Standard or Business Plus

Any of them. The are only two tiers, one for consumer/ free accounts and the other for all the Workspace editions.
Please bear mind, taken from the below link, ...

Note: Additional limits apply for trial accounts. After you convert from a free trial account to a paid subscription, your account limits automatically increase when both of the following are true:

Your domain has cumulatively paid at least USD $100 (or equivalent).
At least 60 days have passed since reaching that payment threshold.


Ref. Quotas for Google Services
Related

Maximum sending rate and daily quota for Gmail+Google Apps Script?
Google Suite App Script Email Sending Limit
How many emails can Google App Script send in a day?

